# What is the generalization of composition in abstract algebra (of rings and fields)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, function-fields

I'm newer to abstract algebra, and recently I came back to the concept of a field after finding rational functions form a field.

But, what I notice is that rational functions (and algebraic functions) are closed under composition.

If I equip a field with $+, \cdot, -, /,$ then what abstraction can I add to include $\circ,$ or function composition?

How does one generalize the idea of functional composition to include it to a field, and does such an object have a name?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: A field is a set of elements that are closed under $+, \cdot, -$ and $/$. Then imagine that same set is also closed under $\circ,$ or that there exists a set closed under $+, \cdot, -, /, \circ.$ An example is the set of rational functions. What is the name of such an object, and is the composition operation generalizable to a class of morphisms over a field more general than a function field?

Comment: Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_ring

Answer (score 2):

You can require the existence of a composition operation $\circ$ on your field, thus creating a composition field. Any field may be considered as a composition field with the "trivial" composition
$f\circ g=0$, or the "constant" composition $f\circ g=f$. For any interesting composition rules, however, you may have to consider more specialized fields. See more in the link provided by healynr.

Comment: Is there anything more fundamental or abstract about composition to the realm of groups or magmas? What is functional composition in its most abstract terms of set elements that we know of? Because otherwise, the composition operation seems limited to function fields of the familiar type, but maybe it could segue into graph theory in some way.

Comment: @StackQuest First of all, the term "composition" isn't really well defined. In the general sense for rings, it would be an operation on a ring $\circ: A\times A\to A$ which distributes over both addition and multiplication, and is associative. If you want to restrict this to groups, this just gives a multiplication on the group, turning it into a ring. Composition as we want to think of it only becomes interesting when we have more structure, and only seems natural when working with actual functions - at least that is my take.